# Installation taking unusually long time

Tags: installation

I am installing 12.04 LTS along side with Windows 7. This installer is taking unusually long time. It has stopped at a point for more than half an hour. It is telling

> Restoring previously installed packages

I am not sure about what's happening. Can you please suggest what has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not re-installing but repairing or updating. Try and re - install. When the dialog box comes, chose "Some thing else" and then change the partitions and then start installing.

For Further help please see:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall